# Typescript:Splice an Object affects the copy object too

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular5

I am trying to remove an object from an array.So that I used `splice` but before splice I made a copy of an object

```
this.program.lstProgramdetails.forEach((lph: any) => {
            this.rtGridUp = Object.assign({}, lph);
            this.rtGridMid = Object.assign({}, lph);
            this.rtGridDown = Object.assign({}, lph);
            lph.Details.forEach((inm: any, index: number) => {              
                if (inm.Track !== null && inm.Track.TrackDateIn !== null) {
                    this.rtGridMid.Details.splice(index, 1);
                    this.rtGridDown.Details.splice(index, 1);
                } else if (inm.Track === null) {
                    this.rtGridUp.Details.splice(index, 1);
                    this.rtGridDown.Details.splice(index, 1);
                } else {
                    this.rtGridUp.Details.splice(index, 1);
                    this.rtGridMid.Details.splice(index, 1);
                }
            });
                    });
```

based on the condition two of the arrays should be sliced and one should get object without splicing.

But watching in console it clears all the 3 arrays.
Is there any possible way to splice that object without affecting the copy object?

Comment: You are creating shallow copies. You either have to make a deep copy using recursion or if you only need copies of the `Details` array you can make shallow copies of it with array destructuring, e.g. `const copy = [...lph.Details]`

Comment: Another way to achieve what you want is to use a pure function like `slice` instead of creating "first level" copies of objects as nested objects remain references.

Comment: Could you pls elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

The issue here is `Object.assign({}, objectToClone)` does create a copy of the object you'd like to clone but keeps references of nested objects

```js
const objectToClone = { a: 'a', b: { b: 'b' } };
const clone = Object.assign({}, objectToClone);

clone.b.b = 'c';
console.log(objectToClone, clone);
```

As you can see, the object isn't deep cloned.

See the [Is this a good way to clone an object in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39736397/is-this-a-good-way-to-clone-an-object-in-es6)
 question for more details.

### A pure function

A pure function is a function which calculates a new value without altering existing ones [More details about pure and impure functions](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-redux-pure-and-impure-functions)

So, to avoid side effects like you are experiencing here. One neat way to achieve this is to use a pure function like `slice` which returns a new value while `splice` alters it and its possible references.

### A way to address the issue

```
this.program.lstProgramdetails.forEach((lph: any) => {
  lph.Details.forEach((inm: any, index: number) => {
    const keys = [null, null];
    if (inm.Track !== null && inm.Track.TrackDateIn !== null) {
      keys = ['rtGridMid', 'rtGridDown'];
    } else if (inm.Track === null) {
      keys = ['rtGridUp', 'rtGridDown'];
    } else {
      keys = ['rtGridUp', 'rtGridMid'];
    }

    // ES7 syntax
    this[keys[0]].Details = [
      ...lph.Details.slice(0, index),
      ...lph.Details.slice(0, index + 1)
    ];
    this[keys[1]].Details = [
      ...lph.Details.slice(0, index),
      ...lph.Details.slice(0, index + 1)
    ];

    // Or if you prefer
    this[keys[0]].Details = lph.Details.slice(0, index).concat(
      lph.Details.slice(0, index + 1)
    );
    this[keys[1]].Details = lph.Details.slice(0, index).concat(
      lph.Details.slice(0, index + 1)
    );
  });
});
```

[This is a cool video explaining it](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-redux-avoiding-array-mutations-with-concat-slice-and-spread) showing ES6 syntax too

I didn't test this code snippet but simply wrote it for an explanation purpose.

I hope you'll find this answer helpful!