# typescript return copy of an object

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

is this the correct way to return a copy of an object?

```js
class ObjectWrapper {
  private _ obj;

  /***
   * Copy object of argument to this._ obj
   */
  constructor (_obj: Object) {
   this._obj = _obj;

  }

  /**
   Return copy of * this._ obj (Return copy this._ obj)
   * @return Object
   */
  get obj () {
  return this._obj;

  }
```

I really was wondering what it means "returning a copy"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this a good way to clone an object in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39736397/is-this-a-good-way-to-clone-an-object-in-es6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are returning the original object. You have several options to copy an object in JS.

**Traditional way through `Object.assign()`:**

```
const target = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const source = { b: 4, c: 5 };

const returnedTarget = Object.assign(target, source);
```

The Object.assign() method only copies enumerable and own properties from a source object to a target object.

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Description)

**ESNext approach with `spread` operator:**

```
const source = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const target = {...source};
```

The Rest/Spread Properties for ECMAScript proposal (stage 4) adds spread properties to object literals. It copies own enumerable properties from a provided object onto a new object.

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals)

Comment: Should't that be const source = { a: 1, b: 2 }; const target = {...source}; ?

Comment: You must mention it `...` does shallow cloning only.  you can see example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605286/what-is-destructuring-assignment-and-its-uses/54605288#54605288